# Using AJAX for displaying Random Products on Home Page

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, ajax, random

Can any one give me an example of Displaying Random Products on homepage using AJAX in Magento 2.3

Comment: What is your current state of the project, can you share some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a module and call it's controller function using ajax and assign value in a div

```
<div class="products wrapper grid random_products" style="display:none;">
    <ol class="products list items product-items row row-wrapper row-5"></ol>
</div>

<script>
require([
    'jquery'
], function($){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/yourcontrollerurl",
        type: "GET",
        data: "",
        success: function (res) {
            if(res.indexOf("find products matching the selection") > -1){
                return;
            }
            var result = jQuery('.product-items', res).html();
            jQuery(".random_products").show();
            jQuery(".random_products.product-items").html(result);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Now in your controller use this:

```
protected $resultPageFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
)
{
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    //Default message if validation failed.
    $block = "<div class=\"message info empty\"><div>We can't find products matching the selection.</div></div>";

    //Getting products list if validation passed

    $viewBlock = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $block = $viewBlock->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\ProductList')
        ->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml')
        ->toHtml();


    //Setting response
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
}
```

Now create `ProductList.php` block `app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/ProductList.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data;

class ProductList extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    protected $collection;
    protected $visibility;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $visibility,
        Data $urlHelper,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->collection = $collection;
        $this->visibility = $visibility;
        parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver, $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
    }

    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
            $limit = 30;
            //Getting configuration
            $this->collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            //Enable filter
            $this->collection->addAttributeToFilter(
                'status', array('eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
            );

            //Stock filter
            $this->collection->joinField(
                'qty', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left'
            );

            $this->collection->setVisibility($this->visibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());

            //Setting up pagination
            $this->collection->setPageSize($limit)
                ->setCurPage(1);

            //This will sort in random order
            $this->collection->getSelect()->orderRand();
        }

        $this->_productCollection = $this->collection;

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

Comment: In which file we need to write the script?

Comment: you can write in any file on home page where you need random products

Comment: answer updated, script was not correct before. It's fine now

Comment: we can write this in phtml file?

Comment: yes in .phtml file

Comment: What are the classes which u hv used in jquery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97758/discussion-between-nafisa-and-shoaib-munir).

Comment: @Nafisa please mark this answer correct if it is helpful to you so that it would be helpful to others in future. As all your requirements has been completed by my solution. The issue you are facing is due to full page cache, you can post separate question for that